# What do you call a document whereby someone promises to pay back borrowed money?

Tags: legalese

I am translating a legal document from Persian into English. It is a loan certification thereby the borrower promises to return the borrowed money in specified period of time.
It has two paragraphs in addition to specifications of both parties. The first one specifies the amount of money paid as loan (the lender is not a bank) and the second paragraph states payback conditions.
I need a title for second paragraph. Its Persian title is "تعهدنامه". I thought of guarantee, warrant, and assurance. But, I am not sure if any of them are legally applicable to this document.

Answer (score 8):

A [**promissory note**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promissory_note)?

> A promissory note is a legal instrument (more particularly, a financial instrument), in which one party (the maker or issuer) promises in writing to pay a determinate sum of money to the other (the payee), either at a fixed or determinable future time or on demand of the payee, under specific terms. If the promissory note is unconditional and readily salable, it is called a negotiable instrument.

Note that this is a little different from a loan contract (which your document's first paragrapph covered).

> A promissory note is very similar to a loan - each is a legally binding contract to unconditionally repay a specified amount within a defined time frame - but a promissory note is generally less detailed and rigid than a loan contract. For one thing, loan agreements often require repayment in instalments, while promissory notes typically do not. Furthermore, a loan agreement usually includes the terms for recourse in the case of default, such as establishing the right to foreclose, while a promissory note does not. Also, while a loan agreement requires signatures from both the borrower and the lender, a promissory note only requires the signature of the borrower

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Or an ***I.O.U.***

Comment: @DanBron: Nice, but I don't think that'll fly in a legal document. If only lawyers had a sense of humor :)

Comment: But the OP asked for suggestions for a title for the second paragraph of what is a loan agreement, not a promissory note. I would suggest it be headed *Repayment terms*.

Comment: @TusharRaj As long as it's signed and dated, it's a legal document.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, *[promissory note](https://en.glosbe.com/fa/en/%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%87%D8%AF%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87)* seems to be a good translation of the Persian title ***تعهدنامه***:

> Translations into English:
>
> ***guarantee*** ...
>
> هيچ مشکلي وجود نداره اگه تو به من يه **تعهدنامه** بدي
>
> *that will be no problem if you'll give me a **promissory note***
>
> *<sub>en.glosbe.com</sub>*